# Bootstrap 3 - Position Columns with Different Widths and Heights Removing Vertical Gutter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 I've arranged columns as shown below.

```
+--------+  +----+
|   1    |  | 2  |
|        |  |    |
+--------+  |    |
            |    |
   (a)      |    |
            +----+
+--------+
|   3    |
|        |
+--------+
```

Note that 2nd column is taller than the first one.

This is what I am doing:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-8'>...</div>
  <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4'>...</div>
  <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-8'>...</div>
</div>
```

I would like to place the 3rd column right below the first one without the space (a). What should I try?

Comment: http://speckyboy.com/2013/07/15/15-jquery-plugins-for-creating-dynamic-layouts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting columns like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-8'>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4'>2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty space will be an empty row just taking that space.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-8'>...</div>
  <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4'>...</div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4'></div>
  <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-8'>...</div>
</div>
```